# Google Search with Image

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, wordpress, google-image-search

I am running Rent a car bussines and I am wondering how to setup image for google search... When someone search for Skoda Fabia, I am SEO optimised enough to be shown on the first page of google search, but I also want picture of the car next to the text (on mobile phones). Is there any way to include it on wordpress? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104987/how-to-change-which-image-from-website-is-shown-in-google-search-result

Comment: @ZeljkaGrahovac The linked question should contain the code on how to achieve that. For WordPress related coding and development questions, it's best to ask those over at our [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site.