# How to show an image beside a web page in Google search results?

Tags: seo, google, images, search-results

How can I specify an image for Google to use alongside my web page in the search results? Please see the following screenshot which illustrates what I am referring to.

[image: screenshot]

Can I control what image is shown here and how? Could this be done through metadata, for example?

Comment: Related: [How to change which image from website is shown in Google search result?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104987/how-to-change-which-image-from-website-is-shown-in-google-search-result)

Answer (score 0):

This image by default taken by Google from your 1st image of the page. But if you are using WordPress then you can set the featured image.

If you are not using WordPress there are some things you should keep in mind:

- Use High-Quality Images
- Ensure the Image is at the Top of the Page
- Add Focus Keyword to ALT Text Naturally
- Optimize Image ALT Text, Title & Caption

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should set the "featured image". But also the position of the image is very important. The desired image should ideally be in the header of the page and near the title

Comment: Can you add any context as to *why* it should be done this way?