# Google Search result: How to show the associated image against it

Tags: seo, google-search, google-index, search, technical-seo

Google search results now show an image against some of the results, as shown below.

How can this be done? Is there some tag that needs to be added on the webpage so that when it gets indexed it shows the image?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you don't have an image shown at all next to your site and you would like one?  Here is a related question about changing it if you already have one: [How to change which image from website is shown in Google search result?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104987/how-to-change-which-image-from-website-is-shown-in-google-search-result)